# Generating pdf documentation from visual studio with docfx throws error: "wkhtmltopdf is a prerequisite when generating PDF"

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, yaml, docfx

I am using docfx to create documentation for a library. I have docfx installed as a NuGet package for visual studio and I would like to create PDF documentation from my solution. Every time I build the project, docfx throws an error that states

> wkhtmltopdf is a prerequisite when generating PDF. Please install it from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and save the executable folder to %PATH% first. Alternatively you can install it from https://chocolatey.org with `choco install wkhtmltopdf`.

I have wkhtmltopdf downloaded and added to PATH.

I  have the JSON file configured to create a PDF document, and a `toc.yml` file inside a folder called `pdf`.

JSON file:

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "*.csproj"
          ],
          "cwd": ".",
          "exclude": [
            "**/obj/**",
            "**/bin/**",
            "_site/**"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dest": "obj/api"
    }
  ],
  "pdf": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/toc.yml",
          "**/toc.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.md",
          "articles/**/toc.yml",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md",
          "pdf/*"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/bin/**",
          "**/obj/**",
          "_site_pdf/**",
          "**/toc.yml",
          "**/toc.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": "pdf/toc.yml"
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/bin/**",
          "**/obj/**",
          "_site_pdf/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/bin/**",
          "**/obj/**",
          "_site_pdf/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "_site_pdf"
  }
}
```

`toc.yml` file:

```
- name: Articles
  href: ../articles/toc.yml
- name: Api Documentation
  href: ../api/toc.yml
```

My library solution folder structure:

```
|- _site
|- api
   |- index.yml
|- articles
   |- intro.md
   |- toc.md
|- pdf
   |- toc.yml
|- docfx.json
|- toc.yml
|- index.yml
(Other visual studio solution files are in this folder)
```

I am expecting a _site_pdf folder to be created upon building the solution, but I am receiving an error stating that wkhtmltopdf is missing, even though it is installed and added to path. I suspect the issue is with either my toc or JSON file but I have very little experience with either so I cannot find the issue.

Comment: Have you checked whether your PATH actually works? Just open a cmd.exe and type `wkhtmltopdf“ it should be able to find and run wkhtmltopdf.exe from anywhere. You could also try to install docfx and wkhtmltopdf using chocolatey. That has always worked reliably for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add below section in your docfx.json under "pdf" section.

```
"wkhtmltopdf": {
  "additionalArguments": "--enable-local-file-access"
},
```